# How to alias ip address of a system

Tags: java, tomcat

How to alias ip address of a system, I am running a application on my local server but typing ip address in URL doesn't looks good.

Comment: Try `hostname`.

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: Unix machine...

Comment: Modifying HOSTS file is the best bet .

Comment: edit your `/etc/hosts` file add a line like `192.168.1.133 yourserver`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is Linux, Unix, Mac (*nix based system) then you add an entry like this in `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       www.example.com
```

If it is Windows based OS then you add can an entry in `%WinDir%\HOSTS` OR `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Comment: for Windows based system, there is HOSTS file too ( at C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS )

Comment: You've been faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a line to your `/etc/hosts` (or your `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) like this:

```
127.0.0.1      myfancyhostname
```

So `http://myfancyhostname/` will point to `127.0.0.1` - like DNS for the poor man. Maybe this helps you to have better looking URLs (I suppose it's for a demo) without changing your hostname or establishing an DNS server.